# Postgres execution plan image

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

is it possible to generate an execution plan in Postgres like the one in MySQL below? thanks

[image]

Comment: In almost all cases the text representation is much more detailed and (in my opinion) easier to read. Most (if not all) of the image visualizations I know for Postgres (or Oracle for that matter) hide many of the important details. That's not so much the case with MySQL as its execution plan is far less detailed. Do try to learn the plan that you get when you just run `explain` or `explain (analyze)`. It **is** worth the effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. pgAdmin does [execution plan visualisation](https://makandracards.com/makandra/35969-pgadmin-has-a-graphical-explain-feature). Same possibility has [OmniDB](https://omnidb.org/en/documentation-en/visualizing-query-plans-en). There is a tool for visualisation plan based on result of Postgres's EXPLAIN command in JSON format [Postgres EXPLAIN Visualizer](http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/about). You can write own tool too, because Postgres can export plans in XML, JSON or YAML format.